# 3rd Party Libraries in Angular CLI which are not on npm

Tags: typescript, angular, npm, angular-cli

I'm currently transferring an app from common Angular 2 to Angular CLI

Now I'm trying to figure out how to import **3rd party libraries** like **orbitcontrols.js** which aren't on `npm` or `bower` to my app.

I found out on https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs that it seems not to be hard to import libraries which are supported by `npm`.

- *How is it with other libraries?*
- *Is it possible at all?*

Versions:

**angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.9**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly yes, but it depends on the library uses too. Still Angular-cli has some problem with the 3rd party library integration. Until They fix it properly, I can give you a hack around. Lets say you want to use `_` of `lodash` in your code. So I will give you my working code scenario-

To install lodash

```
npm install lodash --save
typings install lodash --ambient --save
```

before that make sure you install typings globally

```
npm install typings -g
```

Then in your angular-cli-build.json , make sure it remains like this way

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      ...
      'lodash/**/*.js'
    ]
  });
};
```

and in your system-config.ts:

```
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
 const map: any = {
   'lodash': 'vendor/lodash/lodash.js'
 };

 /** User packages configuration. */
 const packages: any = {
   'lodash': {
     format: 'cjs'
   }
 };
```

in your src/index.html add this line(This is the weird fix)

```
<script src="/vendor/lodash/lodash.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

now in your component where you want to use lodash , write this way

```
declare var _:any;

@Component({
})
export class YourComponent {
  ngOnInit() {
     console.log(_.chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2));
  }
}
```

it worked for me :). I have used enormous 3rd party libraries in my angular2 project through angular-cli. Hope it will help you too

**Edit:**

If you dont get any npm for your third-party libraries. Make an `assets` folder 
under your `src` folder. Then you can add separate folders for `js`,`css` and `images`. 
Put your third-party js inside the `js`folder.
Then you have to reference js file in your `index.html` like this way:

```
<script src="assets/js/your_js.js"></script>
```

Now, when you do `ng build` or `ng serve` it will automatically update the `public` folder with your `assets/js`. Hope you understand the whole scenario :)

Comment: Let me know if you face any problem with `orbitcontrols.js`, I can help you.

Comment: actually i'm not able to do the first step you're describing because orbitcontrols.js is not on npm, so I have to work arround that step somehow else :-)

Comment: No problem, if it doesnot have any npm. I am posting another answer for your convenience

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/orbit-controls are you looking for this ?

Comment: Oh actually Yes! thx ^^ didn't knew it was on npm! Well ok that fixes that problem, but I have to answer the question above anyway, so how I can import libraries wich arn't on npm :-)

Comment: I have updated my answer.  Hope, now you will accept is as an answer

Answer (score 1):

*I'm not familiar with orbitcontrols.js but I will assume it is a global object.*

Place that file within the `public` directory which the CLI creates. I suggest grouping like things in there, so `public/js/orbitcontrols.js`.

Then you can reference that js file in your `index.html` file via:

```
<script src="js/orbitcontrols.js"></script>
```

Comment: OK, so far so good, but how do you import it then in a typescript file for Angular? It won't be a simple import i.e. `import { blabla } from 'orbitcontrols';` or will it?

Comment: I will leave this answer here for it's simplicity but the answer from @pd-farhad is much more comprehensive and I suggest you utilized systemjs to load your library